# How do I remove the Geth "Hunter mode" HUD?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mods

I would like to mod/eliminate the Geth 'Hunter mode' HUD, as it makes my eyes bleed. I am somewhat familiar with the *Mass Effect 3* file structure, but am unsure as to where the HUD images are stored and how to alter them (if possible).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think this is the sort of thing that BioWare bans players for.  (modifying game files)

Comment: QuickBen did you found a way to remove that damned hub? geths are so great and engineer owns in gold runs but that hub gives me an headacke every time.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bannable offense, but given Bioware's effective abandonment of the game at this point (and their general statement of not caring as long as it wasn't a massive advantage over other players when it comes to modding) they don't really seem to care anymore (hence the reason we see modded maps/gamemodes in public lobbies, things like credit reward hacks, zombie mode, etc.)

While I don't personally condone doing mods like this on a non private server (Here's a [promising project](https://github.com/PrivateServerEmulator/ME3PSE) for that if you're interested, no bans and no being tied to the official servers once they're shut down, which is a risk given the small community size nowadays), here's a link for a basic [texmod tutorial](http://www.girlplaysgame.com/mass-effect/mass-effect-how-to-mod-to-your-hearts-content/mass-effect-modding-tutorial-texture-modding/) for replacing the texture once you've found it.

As for finding the texture to use, luckily you don't have to! Someone on the Bioware forums already made it! Assuming it works, my game is uninstalled right now or I'd test it for you, here's a [link to the post in question](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/272815-me3-mod-highres-textures-next-gen-illumination-3d-fix/?p=13249724). Also, here's a [direct link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/wdy8sdezbzvj44b/Clean+Hunter+Mode+HUD+v1.0.tpf) to where it was hosted on mediafire and [here's a version](http://www.mediafire.com/download/sspc5hkkd485wkn/Clean+Hunter+Mode+HUD+v1.0A.tpf) that has the triangle indicator in the upper right corner to help you know it's on if you prefer that.

Happy hunting!

(If you're still playing, this is a rather old post after all...)

Answer (score -3):

To turn off Hunter Mode, simply activate the power a second time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is about leaving the power on, but disabling the display.

Comment: He's asking about removing the texture overlay by modding the game.